# Trouble deleting sections and cells from tableview

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview, cell, sections

I am trying to delete a cell on a tableview that contains sections and this is the error I get:

*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/UITableView.m:1582

The code I am using is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

        let cell = tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
        let staffNic = cell?.textLabel?.text as String!

        var salidaStaff:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "StaffTrabajo")
        salidaStaff.whereKeyDoesNotExist("Salida")
        salidaStaff.whereKey("Nic", equalTo: staffNic)
        salidaStaff.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
            if error == nil{
                for object in objects{
                    let sweet:PFObject = object as PFObject

                    // Busca el id del staff
                    let iddd:String! = sweet.objectId as String!

                    // guarda los datos de salida
                    var query = PFQuery(className:"StaffTrabajo")
                    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iddd) {
                        (gameScore: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            println(error)
                        } else {
                            gameScore["Salida"] = NSDate()
                            gameScore.saveInBackground()
                                                            tableView?.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? This is how I have my datasource setup:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.aventurasUnicas.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "\(self.aventurasUnicas.objectAtIndex(section))"
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var sectionTitle:String = aventurasUnicas.objectAtIndex(section) as String
    var sectionStaff:Array = porAventura[sectionTitle]!
    return sectionStaff.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell;

    // Obtiene el nombre del staff y lo pone en la celda
    var sectionTitle:String = aventurasUnicas.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as String
    var sectionStaff:Array = porAventura[sectionTitle]!
    let staffNic:String = sectionStaff[indexPath.row] as String
    cell.textLabel?.text = staffNic

    // Obtiene el subtitulo
    var subtituloAventura:String = "\(sectionTitle).\(staffNic)" as String
    var sectionStaff2:Array = subtituloTabla[subtituloAventura]!
    let staffNic2:String = sectionStaff2[0] as String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = staffNic2

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailButton
    return cell
    }
```

Comment: When? All the time? Only when deleting the last item in a section? Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to a table view must be performed in concert with changes to the table view's datasource.  So before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, you must first modify the array that backs the table.

Hopefully, in `numberOfRowsInSection` the code refers to an array (call it model) and answers `model.count`.  Hopefully also, the `indexPath.row` where you ask the table to delete is a valid index into model (< model.count).  Before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, delete the item in model at `indexPath.row`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Clearly you understand way more how this works. I just edited my question to show how the tableview is programed. Can you please check it out?

Comment: It looks good.  You should be able to avoid the problem by saying  `self.aventurasUnicas.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)` just before telling the table view to deleteRowsAtIndexPaths.